# Vector as key value pair in Hash map

Tags: c++, vector, hashmap

I'm trying to create a hash_map in C++ with one of the key-value pair of type std::vector. What I'm not getting is how to insert multiple values in vector part of the hash-table?

```
hash_map<string, int> hm;
hm.insert(make_pair("one", 1));
hm.insert(make_pair("three", 2));
```

The above example is a simple way of using hash map without vector as a key-pair value.

The example below uses Vector. I am trying to add multiple int values for each corresponding string value, e.g. => "one" & (1,2,3) instead of "one" & (1).

```
hash_map<string, std::vector<int>> hm;
hm.insert(make_pair("one", ?)); // How do I insert values in both the vector as well as hash_map
hm.insert(make_pair("three", ?)); // How do I insert values in both the vector as well as hash_map
```

If you're wondering why use vectors here, basically I'm trying to add multiple values instead of a single int value foreach corresponding string value.

Comment: Are you using a `hash_map` or `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: I'm using std::hash_map

Comment: Okay, I can answer the question for `std::unordered_map` but I'm not familiar with `std::hash_map`, although I suspect the API is similar.

Comment: @JamesAdkison it's fine, please answer for std::unordered_map instead. I suspect the same. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @qPCR4vir I'm confused by what you're suggesting. I want to add multiple values for the vector<int>, which in turn should be a part of the hash_map itself along with the string value.

Comment: There is no type std::hash_map. Only std::unordered_map, which is in fact a hash map. Are you using some third party library?

Comment: Apparently C++ 11 supports hash_map. Just #include <hash_map>

Comment: I suggest directly that. From my tablet was difficult. See now the new answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
hash_map<string, std::vector<int>> hm;
hm.insert(make_pair("one", vector<int>{1,2,3})); // How do I insert values in both the vector as well as hash_map
hm.insert(make_pair("three", vector<int>{4,5,6}));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>> hm;
hm.emplace("one", std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 3 });
```

If you want to add to it later you can perform:

```
hm["one"].push_back(4);
```

Comment: Thanks. It's exactly the same as std::hash_map. I gave the 'correct answer' to kiviak because he answered 1 min before you did. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @Daqs Yes, the solution is the same. The only difference is this one is more explicit about making use of _move semantics_ (but both solutions should make use of move semantics just the same).

Answer (score -2):

[here compiled](http://cpp.sh/44oy)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int> > hm;
  hm["one"]={1,2,3};
  hm["two"]={5,6,7};
  for (const auto&p : hm)
  {
     std::cout<< p.first << ": ";
     for (const auto &i : p.second)
        std::cout<< i << ", ";
     std::cout<<  std::endl;
  }
}
```

This output:

two: 5, 6, 7,

one: 1, 2, 3,

The previous answers are basically right (I just didn't tested). In the core they use a `vector` constructor which take an initialization list which is the only way to directly create the vector enumerating the values. Nevertheless, I wanted to show what I think is a better way to do what you actually want - to set a new value for a given string key.

The `operator[string]` for this container return a reference for a corresponding value, here  `vector<int>`. If the key is new it first create a new value (vector) too, and insert that pair. Then, the `operator=` of the `vector<int>` will assign from the initialization list. I would said you should use the other variants over this direct variant only if you find a serious reason not to use this, because this is more idiomatic and far more direct.